# Strange null pointer exception in Android Studios

Tags: java, android

So while I was coding, I encountered something logically unexplainable.

```
public class Player {

    ImageView playerImage;
    Bitmap playerBmp;
    InputStream is;
    Drawable drawable;

    public void draw(){

        PlayActivity activity = new PlayActivity();
        playerImage = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.playerImage);

        is = activity.getResources().openRawResource(+R.drawable.main_character_drawing);
        playerBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        drawable = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), playerBmp);
        playerImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

And here is the PlayActivity class

```
public class PlayActivity extends Activity {

    Player player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        player = new Player();
        player.draw();

    }
}
```

And this is the XML for the activity_play

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/playerImage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"/>
```

However, when I run player.draw(), I get a null-pointer exception.
Here is the error log :

```
07-07 17:49:05.291  31892-31892/com.example.testGame.henry. E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testGame.henry./com.example.testGame.henry.PlayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2045)
            at com.example.testGame.henry.Player.draw(Player.java:36)
            at com.example.testGame.henry.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:26)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5244)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Long made short, the problem seems to be this line of code :

```
playerImage = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.playerImage);
```

Is there some sort of reason why this causes a null-pointer exception?
I've also found that if I replaced the 
`draw()` method with `draw(Activity activity)`, and then deleted the line

```
PlayActivity activity = new PlayActivity();
```

and instead simply wrote `player.draw(this)` (`this` being PlayActivity), it would run perfectly fine.

No null-pointer exception, even though the solution I found is the exact same thing as creating an instance of PlayActivity. What is the cause for this?

I don't understand why it's giving a null-pointer exception when I create and use an instance of PlayActivity, yet it doesn't when I pass PlayActivity into a method and use the parameter variable (which is PlayActivity).

Comment: You should not create an Activity using `new`; that's not what they're designed for. See [the tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PlayActivity activity = new PlayActivity();
```

does not give you the existing instance of PlayActivity. It gives you something, if anything, without a valid Context. In order to make it work, you need to use the proper instance of PlayActivity to find the view and inflate it. More or less like you describe in your text.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are calling a new instance of Activity. It has no propagated context. See if this works.

```
public class PlayActivity extends Activity {

    Player player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        player = new Player();
        player.draw(this); <-- THIS

    }
}


public class Player {

    ImageView playerImage;
    Bitmap playerBmp;
    InputStream is;
    Drawable drawable;

    public void draw(Activity activity){ <-- THIS

        playerImage = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.playerImage);

        is = activity.getResources().openRawResource(+R.drawable.main_character_drawing);
        playerBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        drawable = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), playerBmp);
        playerImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```